# Prevent user interaction with modal dialog while automating UI?

Tags: wpf, winapi, modal-dialog, ui-automation, ole

I am automating a "save as" dialog through win32 API in a WPF project. The dialog is called internally from the IOleCommandTarget interface of InfoPath 2013. So I do not have access to how the save as window is initialized as far as a DoModal() method or anything similar.

The issue is I do not want the user to be able to interact with the save as window at all. Some things I have tried are ShowWindow with SW_HIDE, SetWindowPos to move the window off screen or below the main application window, and SetLayeredWindowAttributes to make the window transparent. None of these approaches has worked to hide the dialog.

Comment: Are you sure there's no "save" method you can call to provide a filename to, rather than trying to automate the save dialog?

Comment: @JonathanPotter Unfortunately no, there is not a save method for the Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.FormControl. The raw XML is available through the XMLForm property, but accessing that property has been causing a crash in Windows10 on forms with many data connections.

Comment: There's [BlockInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-blockinput). I've never had a reason to use it, so I cannot comment on whether it solves your problem.

Comment: I've looked into BlockInput as well, but it seems to require administrative rights.